# jQuery and Dart interop with call()

Tags: jquery, dart, interop, dart-js-interop

I'm trying to make basical jQuery interop with Dart in order to use jQuery plugins easily.

I'm trying to figure out a way of achieving both the classical `$("#elementID")` DOM query selection and the plugins getters of `$.fn.pluginX.methodY()`

So far I have developed this

```
@JS()
external JQuery jQuery(String query);

@JS("jQuery")
abstract class JQuery extends intlTelInput.JQuery {
  factory JQuery() {}
  external static Plugins get fn;
}
```

So I can achieve JS `$("#elementID")` with Dart `jQuery("#elementID")`
and JS `$.fn.pluginX.methodY()` with Dart `JQuery.fn.pluginX.methodY()`

But I would like to achieve `JQuery("#elemID")` with something in the class, having the final code sorta like:

```
@JS("jQuery")
abstract class JQuery extends intlTelInput.JQuery {
  factory JQuery() {}
  external static JQuery call(String query); // <- this replacing jQuery(..)
  external static Plugins get fn;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a static method named call to a Dart class won't make JQuery callable. 
Good news is you can achieve the same effect you should just make jQuery a getter that returns a JS interop object that is callable.

Try this instead:

```
    @JS("jQuery")
    external JQuery get jQuery;

    @JS() @anonymous
    abstract class JQuery extends intlTelInput.JQuery {
      external JQuery call(String query);
      external Plugins get fn;
    }
```